# Why would an image on a web page get repositioned after a few refreshs?

Tags: html, css

So I discovered this weird bug, it's so odd and I can't understand why is it doing this. I am using Firefox 3.5.7. It's not happening in Internet Explorer 8 though. So if you visit this website: http://www.ninjasliveclancodes.com/ and look at top right where it says "World War" and pay attention to it because after you refresh a few times you should see it's icon picture move down a little bit closing the gap between the picture and the word "World War". I found out they would all react this way if there was a space within the word. Anyone know why is it doing this? Also, how can I stop it from doing that by either eliminating the gap or have it stay?

**Edit:**
Either way, I would still like to know how can I close in the gap between icon and word. It looks exactly the way I want it in IE8, however, I can't reproduce that in Firefox 3.5.7

```
    <ol>
        <li><a href="http://www.worldwaralliancecodes.net/"><img src="http://www.NinjasLiveClanCodes.com/images/world-war-50.png" />World War</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://imobsterscodes.net/"><img src="http://www.NinjasLiveClanCodes.com/images/imobsters-codes-50.png" />iMobsters</a></li>
        <li class="first"><a href="http://NinjasLiveClanCodes.com/"><img src="http://www.NinjasLiveClanCodes.com/images/ninjas-live.png" />Ninjas</a></li>
    </ol>
```

**Edit2:**
Line-height allowed me to close in the gap. However, does anyone know a way around it?

Comment: Obviously it's a Firefox bug, and this isn't programming related.

Comment: Either way, I would still like to know how can I close in the gap between icon and word.

Comment: You misunderstand: if it isn't programming-related, it shouldn't be on StackOverflow, no matter how mysterious it is.

Comment: ISn't trying to position the icon closer to it's corresponding word using CSS some how programming related? I still need help with that...

Comment: It's still a bug in FF, not a css problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you caught a rendering problem in Firefox. When you click the link, the extra spacing appears.

Try to set line-height on the `#nav ol li` style to override the default line height of the list.

Comment: I just tested it, and it definitely looks exactly the way I want it. However, it still does it but I guess I can't find a way around that bug huh?

Comment: Well, there are some more things to try, like adding a specific br tag between the image and the text instead on relying on the automatic word break to do that, or putting the image and text in separate elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can reproduce it (Firefox 3.5.7 on Windows 7).

I don't think it's the word that is the problem. If you look at the World War image in Firebug, one can see that you have given it a `margin-top` of 45 Pixels. That stays constant, but the three `<li>` elements start at different heights.

Maybe this is some `display: inline-block` oddity, I don't know.

Can you try removing all the whitespaces between the `<ol>` and `<li></li>` tags in your markup? Including line breaks, so that all of the `<ol>` is on one line?

Comment: Actually, Firefox formats it the way you see it in Firebug. My actual source differs. I'll update my post with the source.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ff 3.6 and it seems to be working fine with it. I would suggest you to clear your cache or reloading the page by pressing Control+F5.